# MASM Array not looping

Tags: arrays, loops, masm

Update (2017-11-13):

## I added another variable "index" and set it to zero.  Then, after every .IF loop, I added 4 (DWORD) to the index, which is then passed to the esi register and points to the correct array variable.  I also moved the includedCounter variable outside of the .IF loop.  The answer is now correct!!

I'm trying to loop through an array and sum only the values that are >= 3 && <= 8.  The pointer [ESI] to the array is only "looping" to the first value in the array (3).

Why is ESI not incrementing to the next array?

Values should return "64" for the sum and "13" for the includedCounter.  Current values return as "60" for sum and "20" for includedCounter, which tells me that the first integer in the array is constantly being pointed to, instead of each integer in the array being pointed to.

```
; Calculates the sum of all array elements
; >= "lower" value (3) and <= "higher" value (8).

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
sum DWORD ?              ; EAX - holds sum of included integers 

lower DWORD 3            ; holds lower value
upper DWORD 8            ; holds higher value

;Update (2017-11-13)
index DWORD 0            ; holds index for array
;==============
loopCounter DWORD ?      ; ESI - holds loop array pointer
includedCounter DWORD ?  ; EDX - holds 'included' counter

array DWORD 3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,5,8,9,7,9,3,2,3,8,4    ; values checked
arraySize = ($ - array) / TYPE array                   ; [current location lounter ($) - array / DWORD] = 20

.code
main PROC
 mov eax, sum
 mov ebx, lower
 mov ecx, upper
 mov edx, includedCounter

.WHILE loopCounter < arraySize     ; While loopCounter is less than 20
      ;Update (2017-11-13)
      mov esi, index
      ;===============
      .IF (array[esi] >= ebx) && (array[esi] <= ecx)
      add eax, array[esi]
      inc includedCounter
     .ENDIF
  ;Update (2017-11-13)
  add index, 4
  inc loopCounter
  ;================
.ENDW

; Display values
mov sum, eax
mov eax, sum
call WriteInt
call CrLF

mov eax, includedCounter
call WriteInt
Call CrLF

; Exit program
call WaitMsg

    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: What part of your code do you think should be incrementing `ESI`?

Comment: Well, if ESI is being added to the array to point to a value in the array, then I should increment ESI in order to point to the next value in the array, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your comments (in and out of the code) suggest that you think that incrementing `loopCounter` will somehow automatically increment `ESI` as well.  These are, in fact, distinct entities (one is a register, the other a location in memory), so this "automatic increment" does not happen.  (In fact, more often than not, nothing happens "automatically" in assembly code.)

Comment: OK, I added an index variable and set it to zero.  Then, I added 4 to the index after each .IF loop, and the answer is now correct.

Comment: `.IF`s aren't loops.